# charging system/ 1996 Jeep

Tags: electrical, alternator, jeep

I hooked jumpercables backwards. I changed alternater and battery and it is still not charging. What can it be?

Comment: What's the model and engine size?

Comment: this should be closed as the OP never came back since July to answer a most simple question.

Comment: hey "community" how many times you gonna bump this?

Comment: @agentp bumped yet again, waste of time... just flagged it...

Answer (score 0):

Check all your fuses. Also check fuseable links if applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but if the ECU controls the charging system and alternator, the ECU controls the amp rate controlling the alternator. There should be a Big fuse in the fuse box that might be burnt the ELD module.

I hope this helps.

https://www.civicforums.com/forums/21-i-c-e-electrical/159859-meet-your-eld-electrical-load-detector.html

Comment: While you're on the right track with a ECU controlled alternator, Jeep's don't use an ELD. The PCM has a voltage sense wire (ASD relay output) and will modulate the alternator field circuit.